# Cross Validated Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a moderator on the main site, would you be interested in having your own  Cross Validated contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: CrossValidated Moderator Cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: FWIW, it seems redundant to repeat the text on both front and back.

Comment: @david I don't mind shortening the description on the front side a bit. But I do think it's good to have them on both sides. The way I see it, front side tells about the person, back side tells about the site.

Comment: @Jin Contrary to your last point, the contact lines are *not* optional on the Google Docs form: all three are required.  What should one do to provide only one or two contact points?

Comment: @whuber I meant it can be whatever *other* info you'd like, from my mockup. We will update the template to make the 3rd line optional. meanwhile if you want to fill it out, just put "n/a" in it.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's a great idea.  It would be worth discussing the text on the back: it occurs to me that in its current form it could be misinterpreted as being an experts-only site.

Comment: I copied the text from the /about page. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Jin The text in our faq is a little different and more inclusive: "CrossValidated is for statisticians, data miners, and anyone else doing data analysis or interested in it as a discipline."  It might read better without the "else."

Comment: I have updated the text based on your suggestion.

Comment: @whuber your linguistic skills are sound like your statistics skills!

Answer (score 2):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!